# Java/Android - Passing objects to methods with resources open

Tags: java, android, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Supposing I have a class that holds a reference to an InputStream that is reading from a file, or an OutputStream that is writing to a file (or another example, if you're an Android developer, a MediaPlayer instance).

Knowing that Java passes objects by value, what happens when you have something like the following pseudocode?

```
class MyClass  {


  InputStream is;

  public void read() {
    // initialize inputstream here (assume it's reading from a file that contains the alphabet from A-z)

     is.read();

 }
 public MyClass() {
    this.read();
  }
}


class OtherClass {
  MyClass mine = new MyClass();
  public OtherClass() {
     mine.read();
     LastClass lastClass = new LastClass(mine);

  }
}


class LastClass {
   MyClass his;

   public LastClass(MyClass mc) {
       his = mc;
        his.read();
    }
}
```

My question is, since we're passing objects by value, how are they able to maintain a reference to the open resource? Also, just to be clear, by the time everything is executed, how many instances of MyClass exist?

Answer (score 1):

While it is true that Java is pass-by-value, you must keep in mind that for objects, it is the value of the object's reference that is passed.

Although there may not seem to be a difference between pass-by-reference and passing the value of a reference, their are subtle distinctions.  See [is-java-pass-by-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference) for a more in-dept discussion on the subject.

So to answer your question, in your example you will have one instance of `MyClass` created for each instance of `OtherClass` you create.

As for the input stream, since it is initialized in `MyClass.read()` rather than in the `MyClass` constructor, then we can assume that the file will be opened each time `read()` is called and one byte will be read from the file.  The `InputStream` will stay opened but the next time `read()` is called then a reference to a new `InputStream` will be assigned to the `is` member variable and the old one would be release for garbage collection.  It is hard to say more that that without more code.

When you create an `OtherClass` object, the following happen:

- A new `MyClass` object is created in the heap and a reference to this object is stored in the `mine` member variable.

  - The `MyClass` constructor calls the `read()` method.  So a new `InputStream` is initialize and the first byte is read from the file.
- The `OtherClass` constructor calls `mine.read()`.  So a new `InputStream` is initialize and the first byte is read from the file.
- A new `LastClass` object is created.  The value of the reference to the `MyClass` object stored in variable `mine` is passed to the constructor.

  - This *copy* of the `MyClass` reference is saved in the `his` member variable of the new `LastClass` object.
  - The `LastClass` constructor calls `mine.read()`.  So a new `InputStream` is initialize and the first byte is read from the file.